# What is the best solution to replace weed membrane dug up by the dog?

Tags: border, weedmat

We have pieces of slate around the border with plants and trees. The dog has dug down and pulled the matting apart, so we're looking to re do it all. Are there any solutions that might work better than this fabric material?

Comment: Is the fabric under the slate or under the mulch in the border?

Comment: it seems to just be the slate on the fabric